# Angular: How to interact components from Parent component to child component

Tags: angular

Have two components,one is top panel(parent) and and display(child) components. I tried to enter some values like firstname, lastname, email and click on button to display entered values in child component space(eg: Andy John test@test.com). Could  you please help me how to interaction between parent component to child component while clicking the button.

Here is the [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-communication-between-components-mmmy8e?file=src%2Fapp%2Fparent%2Fparent.component.ts)

Comment: checkout https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: You didn't place your child-selector anywhere in your html. So there will never be anything to display there. Seems to me like you really need to check out the tutorial on https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt3 again :)

Comment: Working https://therichpost.com/angular-12-sending-data-from-parent-component-to-child-component-working/

Answer (score 1):

In your code there was some mistakes

1. You didn't place any Selector ie: <app-child [parentOutputVar]="parentVar">
2. didnt write how to display values in child.

For more details refer :

-> https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs

-> https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

For your purpose please check your edited example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-communication-between-components-coqvnq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.html
using `@Input` directive

**Explanation**

Here in parent components are changed to form with formcontrols -firstname, lastname, email etc. while clicking the button the form values are added into array-parentVar using **.push**.
Here in parent.componet.html, we have added childcomponet directive as

```
<app-child [parentOutputVar]="parentVar"></app-child>
```

The parentVar in parent.component sents data to app-child as input ([parentOutputVar]="parentVar").

The Data will displayed using structural directives -`ngIf` &`ngFor`

Answer (score 1):

You can add properties to the child component like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() firstname: string;
}
```

Communicate them down from the parent's html template like this:

```
<app-child [firstname]="firstname"></app-child>
```

And display them in the child's  html template like this:

```
Hello {{firstname}}
```

Answer (score 1):

For sharing data between parent and child components, we use the `@Input()` and `@Output()` decorators.

The first step is to establish the hierarchy between the parent and the child components. The `<parent-component>` provides context to the `<child-component>`

Out of the two discussed decorators `@Input` and `@Output` the `@Input` decorator lets a parent component update data in the child component and `@Output` decorator lets the child send data to the parent component.

Your requirement specifies, sending data to the child component from the parent component on click of the `submit` button. For which you first need to configure your child component such that,

- In your child.component.ts,
  Add the `@Input()` and decorate the property with it as shown below,

```js
@Input() formData: any = [];
```

- In your parent.component.ts,
  use the child selector `<app-child [formData] = "formValue"></app-child>` as a directive within its template. Here we are using property binding to bind `formValue` property of parent to `formData` property of child.

**TLDR;**

Please find the [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-communication-between-components-3gthms?file=src/app/child/child.component.html) project illustrating parent-to-child data communication.

Here I have updated the example you provided to display the values entered in the form inside your child component, using the `Input()` decorator.